# AJAX Form redirects, but supposed to update target?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an AJAX form defined in Razor, like so:

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveProfile", "Settings",
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "Post",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        UpdateTargetId = "result"
    }))
{
    ...
    ...
```

The rest of the form is very basic. A couple of textboxes and a submit button.

Here's the controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SaveProfile(int AccountID, string DisplayName, string Email)
{
    string message = "Changes saved successfully.";

    var user = db.LoginUsers
        .Where(m => m.ID == AccountID)
        .First();

    if (user != null)
    {
        user.DisplayName = DisplayName;
        user.Email = Email;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    else
        message = "Error. Changes were not saved.";

    return PartialView("_Saved", message);
}
```

And here's the Partial View, `"_Saved"`:

```
@model string

@Model
```

As you can see, it's an extremely basic process. The only issue is that it redirects the page instead of updating my target. I simply cannot figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Are you referencing the "unobtrusive Ajax" JS files?  That is a gotcha, if I recall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my `jqueryval` bundle was not being rendered in my `_Layout`. I assumed since it was a default feature of MVC, it would have done so. Such is not the case.

Be wary of which bundles are being rendered in your layout!